# A network flow with different constraints

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

Considering a simple network flow model: `G = (V,E)`, source node `S`, and sink node `T`. For each edge `E[i]`, its capacity is `C[i]`.

Then the flow `F[i]` on edge `E[i]` is constrained to be either `C[i]` or `0`, that is, `F[i]` belongs to `{0, C[i]}`.

How to compute the maximum flow from `S` to `T`? Is this still a network flow problem?

Comment: Same as the general algorithm. It will be the flow of the minimum cut. Your constraint doesnt change much. btw belongs on http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @UmNyobe are you sure? Let's consider a trivial graph with nodes `{S, M, T}` and edges `{E1 = (S, M), E2 = (M, T)}` with `C(E1) = 1` and `C(E2) = 2`. It seems to me that the max flow under the stated constraints is `0`, which is definitely not the minimum cut.

Comment: The modified problem looks NP hard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The decision variant of your modified flow problem is NP-complete, as evidenced by the fact that the [subset sum problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem) can be reduced to it: For given items w_1, ..., w_n and a sum W, just create a source S connected to every item i via an edge S -> i of capacity w_i. Then connect every item i to a sink t via another edge i -> t of capacity w_i. Add an edge t -> T of capacity W. There exists a subset of items with cumulative weight W iif the S-T max-flow in the graph is W with your modifications.

That said, there is likely no algorithm that solves this problem efficiently *in every case*, but for instances not specifically designed to be hard, you can try an [integer linear program](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_programming) formulation of the problem and use a general ILP solver to find a solution.

There *might* be a pseudopolynomial algorithm if your capacities are integers bounded by a value polynomial in the input size.

Comment: A very insightful and thorough explanation! The "sudden" NP-completeness is a bit surpising to me.

Comment: @Codor Thanks. It's actually not too surprising. With the modification, the min-cut/max-flow duality is gone and what's more, the concept of augmenting paths has no obvious meaning in the new scenario. The greedy local search algorithm employed by max-flow algorithms (incrementally finding augmenting paths) can thus not be applied. Another way to look at it is that with the modification, the solution of the [relaxation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_programming_relaxation) of the linear program does no longer give you a solution for the integer program, unlike in the max-flow case.

Comment: Well, is this because the additional constraints potentially destroy the total unimodularity of the LP's constraint matrix?

Comment: @Codor That's a bit over my head now, I know too little about LP theory to answer that with confidence. We can definitely formulate the modified problem with 0-1 variables, so from what I understand total unimodularity would be sufficient to solve the problem fast (seeing as the solution would be one of the corners of the feasible polyhedron).

Comment: I'm also totally "rusty" in the subject, but thanks anyway for the competent remarks!

Comment: @Codor Yes, Niklas's formulation is not totally unimodular, because the constraint matrix has entries C[i] for the conservation of flow constraints, and, in general, C[i] is not in {-1, 0, 1}.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat Then I am somewhat confused; by what argument is a solution of the LP relaxation of the "classical" flow problem integral, if not by total unimodularity of the constraint matrix?

Comment: @Codor I think the key difference is that in the classical formulation, the variables are not 0-1, but rather just integral, so the matrix entries are in fact in {-1, 0, 1}

Comment: @Codor The classical flow problem has the big numbers on the right-hand side. Niklas scaled the variables to make the right-hand sides 0-1.

Comment: Thanks! I was suspecting of its NP complexity when I asked this question and you made it clear.

Answer (score 0):

Um, no its no longer a well defined flow problem, for the reason that Heuster gives, which is that given two edges connected through a node (with no other connections) the flow must be zero unless the two capacities equal each other. Most generic flow algorithms will fail as they cannot sequentially increase the flow.

Given the extreme restrictivity of this condition on a general graph, I would fall back on a game tree working backwards from the sink. Most nodes of the game tree will terminate quickly as there will be no combination of flows into a node that exactly match the needed outflows. With a reasonable heuristic you can probably find a reasonable search order and terminate the tree without having to search every branch.

In fact, you can probably exclude lots of nodes and remove lots of edges before you start, on the grounds that flows through certain nodes will be trivially impossible.